# Homomorphisms and Groups proof

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Given a one to one group homomorphism $f: G\to H$ and an element $b\in G$ has order $m$, how can I prove $f(b)\in H$ has order $m$ as well?

My idea was that a cyclic group is only homomorphic to another cyclic group.

I feel like this could be used somehow but still not sure where to start.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. To get the best answers, it is needed that you show what you have tried. You can edit your post to add this.

Comment: Actually what is your "normal subgroups" referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f:G\to H$ is a group homomorphism and it is one-to-one. Let $b\in G$ has order $m$. $f^m(b)=f(b^m)=f(e_G)=e_H$.

Now we know that $f(b)$ has finite order. But what if it has order $k$ such that $k<m$? We claim that this cannot be the case. Suppose this is true, then $f^k(b)=e_H$, which implies that $f(b^k)=e_H$. Since $f$ is an injective homomorphism, $\ker{f}={e_G}$. So we claim that we must have $b^k=e_G$. Notice that $k<m$, so actually $b$ has order less than $m$, which is impossible.

Comment: But how do you know f^m (b)=f(b^m)?

Comment: @danny $f(b^{2})=f(b\cdot b)=f(b)\cdot f(b)=f^{2}(b)$ . Now use induction

Comment: Oh I see.  So $f^ m$ (b) concludes to equal e by going through Misakov's solution?

Comment: @danny Sorry there was a typo. Also this only shows that $f^m(b)=e_H$. In order to show that $m$ is the order of $f(b)$, you have to show that $m$ is the least integer satisfying the property.

Comment: Isn't this where the aspect that it is one to one comes in?

Comment: @danny Yes. If $f$ is injective then $\ker(f)={e_G}$.

Comment: @danny I made some edits to my answer, and I think this proof should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @danny No worries. I'm taking algebra as well and I know how it feels.